# When should I use objects.raw() in Django?

Tags: python, database, django

I am quite new to Python and I have seen that both

```
Entries.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM register_entries")
```

and

```
Entries.objects.filter()
```

do the same query.

In which cases is better to use one or the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the database backend that you are using. The first assume that you have a SQL-based database engine. That is not always true. At the opposite, the second one will work in any case (if the backend is designed for). There was for instance few years ago a LDAP backend which was designed so, but LDAP queries do not use SQL language at all.

In all cases, I advice you to **use the second one**. It is the better way to go if you want to make reusable and long-term code.

There are also other ideas to prefer the second one to the first one

- avoiding possible SQL injections ;
- no need to know about database design (table's name, fields' name) ;
- generic code is better than specific one ;
- and moreover, it is shorter...

But you sometimes will have to use the first one when you do specific operations (calling  specific backend's functions), but **avoid them as much as possible**.

In a nutshell, use the second one!!!

Answer (score 1):

From django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries):

> When the model query APIs don’t go far enough, you can fall back to writing raw SQL

For all aspects, django queryset api offers you many options to customize your queries. But in some cases, you need to use very specific queries where django api become insufficient. But before you go for raw SQL, it is best to read all Queryset Api docs and learn everything about django queryset api.